# WPF Trying to add remote images to a listview but only the last one shows up

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I am trying to load remote images in a listview, but only the last image shows up in the list, the rest don't. Here is the code, I have removed some parts of the code at the top. Note that the code compiles ok, just that the remote images don't load(except for the last one in the UI). Any help would be cool!

```
    public async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (youtube_ids.Count > 0)
        {
            DownloadLinks.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            foreach (var youtube_id in youtube_ids)
            {

                var grid = new Grid();
                grid.Width = 400;
                grid.Height = 50;



                // image thumbnail
                var thumb = new Image();

                thumb.Width = 50;
                thumb.MaxHeight = 50;
                thumb.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness { Left = 10 };


                var thumb_file = new BitmapImage(new Uri($"http://img.youtube.com/vi/{youtube_id}/0.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
                thumb.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
                thumb.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                thumb_file.DownloadCompleted += (ob, ev) =>
                {
                    thumb.Source = thumb_file;



                };
                grid.Children.Add(thumb);
                DownloadLinks.Items.Add(grid);

            }
        }
    }
```

There is also a button which I add next to the thumbnail, which shows up fine. Here's a screenshot of what its looking like now
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Take the code where you create the thumb and put it in the loop, so you will be doing it many times instead of just one time.

Comment: @Clemens actually i was just posting a part of the code so i may have missed some lines, I updated the code, I finally add the grid to the listview called DownloadLinks. I also add a button(which is not shown here) and it appears ok right next to where the image should have been. here is what it looks like https://i.imgur.com/3Fdzafx.jpg

Comment: @EdPlunkett ah sorry copy paste mistake, actually all the code is inside the loop.

Comment: Please post working code that definitely exhibits the behavior you're seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating UI elements in code behind, declare an appropriate ItemTemplate

```
<ListView x:Name="images">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Width="50" MaxHeight="50" Margin="10" Source="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

and assign a collection of image URL strings to the ItemsSource property:

```
images.ItemsSource = youtube_ids.Select(
    i => string.Format("http://img.youtube.com/vi/{0}/0.jpg", i));
```

Comment: thanks your answer pointed me in the right direction, I added `<BitmapImage DecodePixelHeight="50" DecodePixelWidth="50" UriSource="{Binding}">` inside `<Image><ImageSource>` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are not looping through the download of the thumb nail based on the code above. Also, in the download complete, try using the event variables rather than relying on a variable outside the event as that can cause issues if reassigned too.

Move the download inside the loop and your grid outside of it.

Comment: realized it was a copy paste error, fixed the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is it looks like you have a class member named "grid" that's outside of the scope of this method. As netniV stated above you should not do this for this very reason.

You're simply re-adding the same grid you've already added previously.

Your code should look like this:

```
public async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (youtube_ids.Count > 0)
    {
        DownloadLinks.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        foreach (var youtube_id in youtube_ids)
        {

                var grid = new Grid();
                grid.Width = 400;
                grid.Height = 50;



            // image thumbnail
            var thumb = new Image();

            thumb.Width = 50;
            thumb.MaxHeight = 50;
            thumb.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness { Left = 10 };


            var thumb_file = new BitmapImage(new Uri($"http://img.youtube.com/vi/{youtube_id}/0.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
            thumb.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
            thumb.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            thumb_file.DownloadCompleted += (ob, ev) =>
            {
                thumb.Source = thumb_file;



            };
            grid.Children.Add(thumb);
            DownloadLinks.Items.Add(grid);
        **}**
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually DownloadLinks is a listview created in XAML. and I am adding grid items to it dynamically. I think that isn't the problem.

Comment: I also wonder about the referenced variable and whether it shiould be using the event variables for safety

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is the problem. Your for loop isn't adding the new Grid to DownloadLinks. it's creating X amount of new grids and than adding 1 thumbnail because your closing foreach } is in the wrong place... which is what I tried to describe above.

Comment: @Slacker yes i realized I made a mistake while copy pasting the code here, just updated the code in the question. All the code is actually inside the loop.

Comment: @BA Okay that makes more sense. Honestly if you're using WPF Clemens has the better solution. When working with WPF I try not to do any code behind, as I usually run into problems like this.

Comment: @Slacker thanks, I am new to wpf, I am going to give his code a try soon.